# Invalid variable selection

Tags: c

I am  learning c language from a book named 'Let us C' by Yashavant Kanetkar in this book in one problem we are asked to find whether the variable is valid or not in c and there is one variable "_main()" (without double inverted commas) and as normal rules we know that we cannot use () in variable name but in the solution book this variable is said to be valid. So please help me I'm new to c so please make the answer as simple as possible.

```
//this is the variable
_main()
```

Now I tried creating a small hello world program with using this variable and as expected i got an error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int _main();
    _main() = 1234;
    printf("%d", _main())

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_main()` is not a valid variable name. `int _main();` is a valid _function_ declaration.

Comment: ... and just only `printf(... _main()` is calling this function.

Comment: _solution book this variable is said to be valid ?_ The author is wrong about this. This `int _main();` compiler can treat as declaration of `_main()` function.

Comment: @Achal I also thought the same but at first I doubt myself as I'm new to c thanks now understood that this is a misprint author can't be wrong as this book is the bestseller in programming.

Comment: This question is **worthless** without a word-exact excerpt from the book.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the book was misprinted so am I supposed to delete this answer now?

Comment: @TusharSharma a question about a misprint in a popular book can be useful to future readers. A question that really is about misquoting and misunderstanding what is said in the book without a verbatim quote that could be found by Google - worthless.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

_main() is NOT a valid name for a c variable. you may not use parenthesizes in variable name.

> All variable names must begin with a letter of the alphabet or an
>   underscore( _ ).  For beginning programmers, it may be easier to begin
>   all variable names with a letter of the alphabet.
>
> After the first initial letter, variable names can also contain
>   letters and numbers.  No spaces or special characters, however, are
>   allowed.
>
> Uppercase characters are distinct from lowercase characters.  Using
>   all uppercase letters is used primarily to identify constant
>   variables.

Taken from [here](https://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/DataBasics/naming.htm)

Comment: Err, how does this answer the question?

Comment: OK i will clarify

Comment: Got it looks like there is a misprint in the book at first I also thought the same but the book is of an honorable author so I thought maybe I lack knowledge.

Comment: The quoted text verses about C++, although this specific point being common between the two languages it is important to note that C++ is a whole complete and different language than C. C++ **is not** just a C with steroids as ppl like to say. I will remove my downvote if you change the reference to a valid C one.

Comment: @dedecos actually it is for C. I agree last bullet referring to C++ is misleading. I will remove it.

Comment: @nivpeled "Variable names in Visual C++ can range" <- first phrase of the quoted text.

Comment: @dedecos yes, thanks. corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can't name a variable using `()` anywhere in its declaration.

By the code you gave I will point the problematic lines.

> `int _main();`

Here you forward-declare a function called `_main`. You are telling the compiler that somewhere in the code you have defined this function. Here you are not declaring a variable though.

> `_main() = 1234;`

C language have the idea of l-values and r-values. In a nutshell l-values are all names in code that can store some value (e.g. variables), r-values are the values that can be stored in l-values. As a rule you can only assign any value to a l-value (the LHS of the assignment must be a l-value). That said and all function returns being r-values you can't put it on the left-hand side of an assignment.

> `printf("%d", _main())`

2 problems: A- you forgot to write `;` at the end of the line and B- the name `_main()` can not be resolved as it is not defined in the code you wrote. When compiling this code, the linker will try to find where is defined the function called `_main` and will find nothing.